# Let $p$ and $q$ be primes with $q>p$, why $q∣(p^2-1)$ holds only when $p=2$ and $q=3$?

Tags: number-theory

This is a statement i found in my teacher's proof of a theorem on an algebra course, he didn't explain it probably because it is trivial. But I really stucked here when understanding the proof, can someone tell me or give some hints about that why other cases can not happen? Thanks.

Comment: $p^2-1=(p-1)(p+1)$. So $q\mid(p-1)(p+1)$ implies $q\mid p-1$ or $q\mid p+1$.

Comment: In particular, requires $q \leq p+1.$ With $q > p,$ this means $q = p+1.$ The only consecutive primes are $2,3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$q|(p^2 -1)$,  $q>p,$  $q,p$ prime.

Then $q|(p-1)(p+1)$.

Implies:

$q|(p-1)$ or $q|(p+1)$.

(Euclid's Lemma)

Since $q>p$ , $q\not \mid (p-1)$.

Hence $q|(p+1)$.

$q>p$ implies $q\ge p+1$.

1) If $q=(p+1)$ , then

a) $p$ is odd and $q$ is even, or

b) $p$ is even and $q$ is odd.

Note:

The only even prime is $2$, it is the smallest prime.

All other primes are odd and greater

than 2.

Hence only b) is viable :

$p=2, q=3.$

2) If $q > p+1$, then $ q\not | p+1.$

Comment: Thanks！The key point I missed is the Euclid’s Lemma. Thanks for mentioning it, I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do is think about the fact that all primes that aren't two are odd. So, in that case you would have $$q^2 -1$$ be even.

And you can't have an odd divide an even.

Comment: Odd numbers divide even numbers all the time. For example, $3$ divides $12$.

Comment: Yeah I mixed up p and q, and also forgot which way "divides" went (I always think of the first one as the numerator and it messed me up)